# How to Install NVIDIA Cuda without EULA/prompts?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, vagrant

I'm currently installing with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
curl -O "http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/installers/cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run"
chmod +x cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run
sudo ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/
```

Then, EULA appears and some prompts. I'd like to create a provision script that automates this installation.

Thanks.

Comment: I will definitely want to follow this.  I get nervous enough when I find myself clicking the EULA agreements for others I'm helping.  I can't imagine the fallout from circumnavigating a third party's obligation to see and agree to a EULA agreement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the installer's built-in help text, you should be able to do that by adding the command-line option `-silent`:

```
$ ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --help
Options:
   -help                      : Print help message
   -driver                    : Install NVIDIA Display Driver
   -uninstall                 : Uninstall NVIDIA Display Driver
   -toolkit                   : Install CUDA 6.5 Toolkit (default: /usr/local/cuda-6.5)
   -toolkitpath=        : Specify a custom path for CUDA location
   -samples                   : Install CUDA 6.5 Samples (default: /usr/local/cuda-6.5/samples)
   -samplespath=        : Specify a custom path for Samples location
   -silent                    : Run in silent mode. Implies acceptance of the EULA
   -verbose                   : Run in verbose mode
   -extract=            : Extract individual installers from the .run file to PATH
   -no-opengl-libs            : Install driver support for Optimus
   -override                  : Overrides the installation checks (compiler, lib, etc)
   -kernel-source-path= : Points to a non-default kernel source location
   -tmpdir              : Use  as temporary directory - useful when /tmp is noexec
```

Comment: Note that -silent also has other effects, such as accepting all the default values for other options. It does not simply accept the EULA

Comment: Note that the -s switch does not actually make the install silent, a number of notices are still presented: - Warnings regarding missing X Windows (when installing in an env without a GUI) - Warnings regarding being unable to find locations for x86/32b compatibility libraries on x64 environments. - Install complete